Swap failed because of frozen token account
I bought some coins ( https://dexscreener.com/solana/akpjw4wuzag2kyiwvuggcqghdn1ehqk5uuwjz9g9tojy ) using Raidium. When I tried to sell it, I coudnt - I see the messages "We were unable to complete the SWAP, please try again later. The token account is frozen"
But the coin still trading, I could earn some money but I cant bacause of this problem.
Here is Solscan account  https://solscan.io/account/B5nEmxWQeg3wKYUUzn8fPZWfKhUoxQp3eYxZPo1ajJ6A
What is the problem with Solana? How to ask support to fix it?

the problem is not really from solana, a frozen account mean that the issuer of the token has frozen your account (only for this token), meaning you can't perform a transaction involving this token. Might be a scammer token ? You should look for some help in their telegram/discord community, that what i would do
